# Run class evaluation from Application Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a wonderful question, that I'm sure someone has come across before.

I have some classes that are inheriting from ApplicationRecord and ApplicationRecord inherits from ActiveRecord::Base.

Lets call my classes Post, Comment, Author.

Now I have multiple concerns for each of these things which have inclusions.  So that I do not have to hard code in each of the concerns I have a ConcernDirectory.

The call to it essentially runs each of the concerns for the model.

```
ConcernDirectory.inclusions(self).each{ |inclusion| include inclusion }
```

If I have this in each model everything works fine.

However if I put this into the parent (ApplicationRecord) it no longer works.

When I run it in ApplicationRecord, self points to ApplicationRecord(abstract).  How do I get the call from ApplicationRecord to refer to the child from which the call came?

eg.

```
post = Post.new
```

when it instantiates its parent class's

```
--------------.is_a?(::Post)
```

would be true from the ApplicationRecord.

What is -----------?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: where and how exactly do you call it?

Comment: and btw, why not include everything directly into ApplicationRecord and go the complex way of having something that does the inclusion?